# Display Specific Value in View ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

For my website, I am able to display every detail of the Account Table in my database. My `AccountStatus` has 2 values inside the database; "Approved" and "Rejected". However, I want to display the details on my website only if the value of the `AccountStatus` is "Approved".

I am currently using ASP.net core MVC with EF core and SQL server.

Model:

```
public class AccountModel
   {
       [Key]
       public Guid AccountID { get; set; }

       public DateTime AccountCreationDateTime { get; set; }

       public string AccountStatus { get; set; }
   }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Account()
       {
           return View(await _context.Account.ToListAsync());
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Account()
       {
           return View(await _context.Account.Where(s => s.AccountStatus == "Approved").ToListAsync());
       }
```

I would advice you to learn some more about the basics of queries an linq:
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx

PS: Better to put your AccountStatus in a seperate table instead of using a string

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Asp.net. Why is it better to put the AccountStatus in a separate table?